# KNEM cookie and declared region

Tags: linux-kernel

First question is PROT_WRITE and PROT_READ i wasn't able to find anywhere and it's giving me a hard time compiling. I replaced with 0 and 1 but it doesn't seem to work.

Second, "rejected (unexisting region cookie)"

```
int rank;
MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank );
MPI_Win win;
int knem_fd = open("/dev/knem", O_RDWR);
int err;
uint64_t size = 64;

if( rank == 0 ){
    char *inbuf = malloc(size);
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        inbuf[i] = rand() % 26 + 97;

    print_array( inbuf, size, '0' );

    struct knem_cmd_create_region create;
    struct knem_cmd_param_iovec knem_iov[1];

    knem_iov[0].base = (uint64_t)&inbuf;
    knem_iov[0].len = size;

    create.iovec_array = (uintptr_t) &knem_iov[0];
    create.iovec_nr = 1;
    create.flags = KNEM_FLAG_SINGLEUSE;
    //create.protection = 1;
    err = ioctl( knem_fd, KNEM_CMD_CREATE_REGION, &create );

    MPI_Send( &(create.cookie), 1, MPI_UINT64_T, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    MPI_Barrier( MPI_COMM_WORLD );

} else if( rank == 1 ){
    char *obuf = malloc(size);
    int err;

    struct knem_cmd_copy copy;
    struct knem_cmd_create_region create;
    struct knem_cmd_param_iovec knem_iov[1];

    knem_iov[0].base = (uint64_t)&obuf;
    knem_iov[0].len = size;

    create.iovec_array = (uintptr_t) &knem_iov[0];
    create.iovec_nr = 1;
    //create.protection = 0;
    create.flags = KNEM_FLAG_SINGLEUSE;

    err = ioctl( knem_fd, KNEM_CMD_CREATE_REGION, &create );

    MPI_Recv( &(copy.src_cookie), 1, MPI_UINT64_T, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );

    copy.src_offset = 0;
    copy.dst_cookie = create.cookie;
    copy.dst_offset = 0;
    copy.flags = 0;
    err = ioctl(knem_fd, KNEM_CMD_COPY, &copy);

    print_array( obuf, size, '1' );
    MPI_Barrier( MPI_COMM_WORLD );
}
```

0 and 1 both create a region, 0 sends its cookie to 1 and 1 goes in grab data from 0. I checked the received cookie is the same as the send cookie, but it just failed to find the declared region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROT_READ and PROT_WRITE are mmap flags, you need to include sys/mman.h to get them. In the second part of the code, you need to set copy.src_cookie to create.cookie (or just use an inline copy to avoid creating that region at all since it'll be destroyed immediately because of the SINGLEUSE flag). Also, make sure ou check the return values of all ioctl before continuing. Copy cannot work if create.cookie wasn't initialized because the create ioctl failed.